# Google Play - promoting a release from internal track to production & Google review

Tags: android, google-play-console

We are planning to move a version from Internal Track to Production.

Will this version go through another Google review?

Also, if we have `Managed publishing on - you control when approved updates are published`, does that mean after the `production review` (if it has to go through another one) we would need to press rollout (release to store)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

We did have to go through another review and I actually found a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130176/google-play-timed-publishing).

The bottom line is the text google has on the button that puts the release to review when you are using Timed Publishing is misleading (it should say `Put to Review` rather than `Start rollout to production`)

Attached is a screen shot after the review was done showing the `Review and Publish` button that appears after the review.

[image: managed publishing on google play]

Comment: This is still misleading today. when you hit the `Start rollout to production`' button on the Production release menu, and then approve the `This will now be available to all Play Group users` dialog, assuming Managed publishing is ON - **it won't release** until you hit 'Publish Changes' manually.